# Spring Boot Multi tenancy with oauth

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, multi-tenant

I have a working standard Spring Boot/Hibernate multi tenancy (schema) solution but failing to intercept the oauth token request on /oauth/token.

It seems that HandlerInterceptor instances are getting called for any request but not those pointing to my token endpoint. Which is a problem as I require multi tenancy there.

So I need some class that gets called at the start of any request to extract the tenant information from the request which will then be stored in some ThreadLocal. And also I need a method called after the request processing to remove the tenant information from the ThreadLocal to be safe.

I guess a WebFilter is not sufficient as it will get called only once per request. And any MVC handler/interceptor is not getting called for my oauth endpoints which are configured by spring boot auto configuration and seem to bypass the mvc invocation.

Can the oauth resource get intercepted by mvc handlers? 
Is there any other solution to my problem than using RequestContextHolder?

Any ideas hints - thanks in advance!
Gerrit

Comment: Does this help : http://projects.spring.io/spring-security-oauth/docs/oauth2.html

Comment: this does not addresses any of my questions...

Comment: @xstring: did you find solution of this problem.

Comment: Yes, but not working for the company anymore where i wrote that stuff so I can't post the solution here. Sry.